# How can i download expect from linux?

Tags: installation, tcl, expect, redhat

When i went for downloading expect it says Expect-5.43.0 [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/general/expect.html) and the required tcl is
Tcl-8.4.18

This is my current tcl version

```
% puts $tcl_version
8.4
% info patchlevel
8.4.13
```

will  Expect-5.43.0 work with tcl  8.4.13 or i have to download the expect for my tcl version 8.4.13.

Anyway, i tried with the above to download

I tried [this](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/expect/expect-5.43.0.tar.gz/230400129630335b3060a42f66fec11d/) link for expect-5.43.0.tar.gz.
Left clicked on the   expect-5.43.0.tar.gz link and copyied the link and pasted into my linux box with wget, but it failed.

```
[root@mailserver ~]# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-164.el5 (mockbuild@x86-003.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009
```

Comment: Tcl 8.4 is end of life. Your favorite package manager should have a newer version. If not, nag the package mantainer.

Comment: How did it fail? (There's not much difference between 8.4.13 and 8.4.20; virtually all of it is bugfixes. You will want to upgrade though, as one of those bugfixes was to allow Tcl's `configure` script to work with relatively recent versions of `/bin/sh`…)